# Should we make country tags visually distinct?

Tags: feature-request, tagging, design

Someone posted [this workplace.SE meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3631/should-we-make-country-tags-visually-distinct) in chat earlier, and I think this idea is just so good for Travel.SE.

The idea basically is about adding country flags to the country tags, something like:

[image]

**How can we implement that here?**

Comment: V. nice, we should be leading the way in this initiative.

Comment: This has now got to Meta.SE - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279254/should-we-make-country-tags-visually-distinct

Comment: Would continent tags like 'Africa' or 'Asia' get a little outline shape of the continent as an icon ?

Comment: @blackbird57 Anything involving maps gets too political too quickly, e.g. is Georgia part of Europe or Asia? Is Indonesia Asia or Oceania? Better to stick to countries, where we can fall back on ISO-3166 assignments (thus, Taiwan would get a flag, but Kosovo would not).

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged feature-request?

Comment: @CMaster yes, i edited it..

Comment: Older: *[Country tag design](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152)*

Answer (score 15):

The problem that WSE has - people ignoring country tags - isn't particuarly a problem here. In general, in fact, I don't think adding little flags solves any problems we have.

But it looks nice, and can only boost clarity. If it's possible I think we should go for it.

Bonus Q: Do we also do this for "citizens" tags?

Comment: Main purpose is as you said, it looks nice, and yes, I think we should add it for citizen tags as well.

Comment: Suggestion for the citizen tags - could it be flag + passport icon (or person, something like that).

Comment: Cmaster very nice, a person icon  with the flag is nice. Can we add a person with a turban for Arab countries? Just saying 

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis If whatsapp taught us anything is that if we add a person icon we'll also need an a yellow person-emoji, a purple person-emoji, a brown person-emoji...

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the flags in country tags and I would also like them in 'citizen of ... country' tags.
I use other sites, and in some of them flag are or have been used. 
In case of Yahoo Answers 'have been' and my friends there and I have not been happy to see them disappear.

It did not solve all 'wrong country for the answer' problems but that was mostly because they were added based on the log-in country rather than based on the text as we do here.

Answer (score -2):

I am going to echo [Monica's answer on Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3639) and say that I'd rather have a generic and neutral icon like a globe next to the country name, rather than a flag:

> While arbitrary icons would cause confusion for people who've seen this on SO, thinking our icons are corporate sponsors too, I think a single, unambiguous icon -- such as a globe -- that's used on all the location tags would avoid that problem. An earlier version of this answer proposed using flags (so the tags would have different icons), but, on reflection, a single icon that signals "hey, there's a location tag here (so pay attention to it)" would be sufficient. I hope it would also be easier to manage.

Comment: That would work for the specific case of Workplace.SE, not for Travel.SE. Almost every question here is about a different place, while on Workplace.SE it is a different case and these few questions about a specific place should be distinct.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis a generic globe icon would have pretty much no benefit for TSE

Comment: @CMaster They'd work in pointing out "hey there's a country tag here". Which is IMHO more than enough to make people pay attention to a tag. Also, asking for a common solution across various SE sites might help in having the feature-request implemented.

Comment: @CMaster that's exactly my point. In addition to that, we have the whole map as the background in TSE ;)

Comment: @JoErNanO that would be useful when questions with country tags are rare and people should pay attention to that, that's not the case for TSE, almost ALL questions are country specific here.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis sorry, I was agreeing with you. I somehow missed a word

Comment: @JoErNanO bit late here but *I'd rather have a [...] globe next to the country name, rather than a globe* kinda contradicts :P